# solve :$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

solve :

$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}=1$$

MY Try :

$$\sqrt{x+1}=1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}\\
x+1=1+1-\frac{1}{x}+2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}$$

Now what ?

Comment: Move everything that is not under the radical to one side, square both sides again.

Comment: Now you square it again. Just like you did before. First gather the other non-square root terms onto the lefthand side. After the second squaring, you'll be free of square roots and you're equation will be easier to solve.

Comment: Multiply by $x$ and square after rearranging the terms you get $$-x^4+2x^3+x^2-2x=1$$ or $$(x^2-x-1)^2=0$$ or $$x^2-x-1=0$$ and thus $$x=\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt5}2$$ By inspection, only the solution $$\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{x=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt5}2}$$ is correct

Answer (score 4):

I start from the equation stated in the title of your question. Square it gives
 $$ x+ 2 - \frac{1}{x} -2 \sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}} = 1 $$ 
Then I define $ y := x - \frac{1}{x} $

The equation can thus be rewritten as follows 
$$ y - 2 \sqrt{y} + 1 = 0 $$ 
which is 
$$ (\sqrt{y} - 1)^2 = 0 $$
hence $y=1$ and then I solve for x $ x - \frac{1}{x} = 1 $ that is $ \frac{x^2 - 1}{x} = 1 $ which gives $ x = \frac{1+- \sqrt5}{2} $

There are probably mistakes since I did it very quickly but the idea should be there.

EDIT : I see the question was awnsered just before with same solution, it is still good to have an other way to solve your equation.

Comment: good substitution idea.

Comment: I really like your substitution. Pretty cool how that problem relates to phi.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was surprised to come up with x = phi. Maybe there is some interpretation to give to this equation that I don't see that would've suggested that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring the original equation on both sides (so we have to check our final solutions for fake ones) we get (after rearranging):

$$2\sqrt{x-\frac1x} = 1+x - \frac{1}{x}\tag{1}$$

and having the square on one side we square yet again (same caveat as earlier):

$$4(x-\frac{1}{x})=(1+x-\frac{1}{x})^2 = 1+x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} -2 -\frac{2}{x} + 2x$$

which I think simplified becomes

$$2x  - \frac{2}{x} = -1 + x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\tag{2}$$

Multiplying by $x^2$ then gives:

$$2x^3 - 2x = -x^2 + x^4 + 1$$

or $$x^4 - 2x^3 -x^2 +2x +1 = (x^2 -x -1)^2 = 0$$

And now can find the two real solutions to that last equation as $x = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Now check these with a calculator in the original equation.